# Simulated methods in Javascript -- how do they work?

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

I'm new to Javascript. I've seen code like this:

```
class Reservation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {...}
}
```

As far as I can tell by searching, `handleInputChange` is not a method, but a standalone function, and `bind` makes it behave more like a method. Can someone explain more about what's happening under the hood? Is it something like this?

1. On creation of a `Reservation` object, `handleInputChange` is bound to a fresh lambda.
2. The code in the constructor then rebinds it to some function object that wraps/modifies the lambda and binds `this` inside it.

Is this the only way to create a method in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

> handleInputChange is not a method, but a standalone function

Methods are just functions which are stored as object properties.

> bind makes it behave more like a method.

In this case, it would make it act like it was called as a method of the object *even if it was copied somewhere else* (e.g. with `someInput.addEventListener('change', this.handleInputChange)`) and called in a different context.

> Is this the only way to create a method in JavaScript?

No.

```
const foo = new Reservation
foo.handleInputChange(...)
```

… would work just fine even without the rebinding.